# Do you add extra oil when replacing eggs in baked goods?

Tags: substitutions, eggs, oil, muffins

I usually use applesauce to replace eggs in muffins, but I realize that I am losing out on some of the fat that an egg yolk would provide. Should I add more oil when I do this? If so, how much?

If it helps, here is the recipe I use to make muffins: https://togetherasfamily.com/mini-chocolate-chip-muffins/

I replace one egg with 3 tbsp of applesauce and 1/8 tsp baking soda. Is there a rule for how much oil I should add per egg?

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 5):

Eggs are about 10% fat by weight, a large egg is about 50g, so you would lose 5g of fat in the recipe per egg, which is just over a teaspoon of oil. Whether or not you add it depends on what you want out of the recipe. If you are taking eggs out to reduce fat then you don't need to add anything, if you want to keep the richness and consistency then a splash of oil or butter would be a good thing.